# MobileFirst JavaScript adapter load local config file

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I am creating multiple applications which works the same. For every application I use an adapter which contains the same procedures, but perform the request to a different back end (same host, only different path).

The thing I would like is to add a configuration file (json / xml) to the adapters which I can load and fetch some information from such as the path so I know which back end I need to call. The configuration is now in top of the file, but in the future it would be lovely to be able to update the adapter without changing the configuration afterwards.

Is there a way to load a second file located in the same directory (as where the adapter xml and implementation file are)? I tried using XMLHttpRequest, but this doesn't work as it is unavailable. The code I tried, but couldn't test as the fifth line already breaks.

```
var config = null;

function loadConfiguration() {   

    var loader = new XMLHttpRequest();
    loader.overrideMimeType('application/json');

    loader.open('GET', 'config.json', false);
    loader.onreadystatechange = function () {

        // Only for async calls.
        config = loader.responseText;

    };

    config = loader.send();  
 }
```

If there is a better way, I would love to hear it! We upgraded to MFPF 7.0 if there are any new possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with JavaScript adapters, however in MFPF 7.0 there is a new type of adapters: Java adapters. Using Java adapters you can achieve this.

The following blog post explains how you can provide a single adapter that will allow you to point to different hosts or differents paths in the same host, etc...

See here: [Changing the adapter host](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2015/03/20/changing-adapter-host-runtime/) at runtime